# How to get Outlook calendars from global address book?

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, office-interop

I work with Microsoft Office Interop Outlook. I'd like to get the calendar from people in the global address book.

I already know how to get data from adress book with `Session.GetGlobalAddressList()` or my personal calendar with `GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);`

Is-it possible to get calendar data from the global address list ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, call `Namespace.CreateRecipient`, then pass the returned Recipient object to `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`.